# High usage in CPU, low IO wait and low IDLE time with only 2 processes running, how do I identify the process and script that's causing this?

Tags: linux

```
iotop
top
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

I am running these, but I am not sure how to be 100% sure what's causing the issue. I did top and saw that idle time was low and I/O wait was high and CPU user time was high, I think the culprit is a rsync process, but the top process always shows me that the mysqld process is the process that uses the most CPU. So I am not sure how to check, I tried SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, but it doesn't show me anything particularly strange, and doesn't tell me that there's a rsync, at least I don't see any SQL query, maybe I missed it meaning it was already gone by the time I ran it. There's a lot of sleeping processes. 603 and only 2 not sleeping. The % the mysqld process uses is 695% in terms of CPU, and the other processes below it are using roughly between 20% to 10% and they're php-fpm, redis and php processes. So how do I know if I should upgrade or not? I think we need to upgrade, but I am not sure how to check the exact reason why.

Comment: Check the slow query log.

Comment: What's that? Where can I find it?

Comment: It's wherever you specified it to be in your MySQL configuration.